# MySQL select query, adding max value from another table

Tags: mysql

Trying to add another column with a new  table, would appreciate any help/suggestions!

Current query:

```
SELECT parent.name AS parentname, a.name AS accname, 
parent.code AS parentcode, a.code AS acccode, 
parent.guid AS parentguid, a.guid AS accguid, 
a.account_type AS accttype, 
sum(case when date_format(post_date, '%Y-%m-%d') <= '2017-12-31' then (s.value_num/s.value_denom) else '0' end) AS 'value2017-12-31', 
sum(case when date_format(post_date, '%Y-%m-%d') <= '2018-01-25' then (s.value_num/s.value_denom) else '0' end) AS 'value2018-01-25'

FROM transactions AS t INNER JOIN splits AS s ON s.tx_guid = t.guid 
INNER JOIN accounts AS a ON a.guid = s.account_guid 
INNER JOIN accounts AS parent ON parent.guid = a.parent_guid 
WHERE a.hidden = 0 AND a.account_type NOT IN ('INCOME', 'EXPENSE')
AND parent.name <>'' 
AND a.guid = '3f3fc442a98225f481bb72e0fd526cbb'
GROUP by accname, parentname ORDER by acccode
```

And that works fine, gives 1 row of results.  I'd now like to add another column to the results, I believe a left outer join from the prices table of the record that is the closest date before 2017-12-31.  My attempt:

```
SELECT parent.name AS parentname, a.name AS accname, 
parent.code AS parentcode, a.code AS acccode, 
parent.guid AS parentguid, a.guid AS accguid, 
a.account_type AS accttype, 
sum(case when date_format(post_date, '%Y-%m-%d') <= '2017-12-31' then (s.value_num/s.value_denom) else '0' end) AS 'value2017-12-31', 
sum(case when date_format(post_date, '%Y-%m-%d') <= '2018-01-25' then (s.value_num/s.value_denom) else '0' end) AS 'value2018-01-25',
MAX(case when date_format(p.date, '%Y-%m-%d') <= '2017-12-31' then (p.value_num/p.value_denom) else '0' end) AS 'price2017-12-31'

FROM transactions AS t INNER JOIN splits AS s ON s.tx_guid = t.guid 
INNER JOIN accounts AS a ON a.guid = s.account_guid 
INNER JOIN accounts AS parent ON parent.guid = a.parent_guid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN prices as p ON p.commodity_guid = a.commodity_guid
WHERE a.hidden = 0 AND a.account_type NOT IN ('INCOME', 'EXPENSE')
AND parent.name <>'' 
AND a.guid = '3f3fc442a98225f481bb72e0fd526cbb'
GROUP by accname, parentname ORDER by acccode
```

It's obviously incorrect as it's now changing the values of value2017-12-31 and value2018-01-25.  I get the price correctly using a separate query:

```
SELECT p.value_num/p.value_denom as calcprice 
  FROM `prices` as p 
 WHERE commodity_guid = '77be249d12d9889e90f08dde7c671eb0' 
   AND date_format(p.date, '%Y-%m-%d') <= '2017-12-31' 
 order 
    by date DESC 
 limit 1
```

Is there any way to combine them rather than using temp tables?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I recommend creating a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with sample data, and an expected output.

Comment: It is probably how you are grouping it.  I would consider using an OVER() clause if you want it in one query.  Also you may want to double check you are not getting any cartesian products since you are joining again to the same table.